no output from Shell script getting data from vnstat
I have a shell script that which I am facing an issue with the data output is string I think it is empty string and what output should be a float I am not shell script coder and never did but I am looking for someone to fix it. the script is used to take values from bandwidth table created using vnstat package.
tempout1=$(vnstat -h| tail -n 2| awk -F\  '{ print $11}'| tail -n 1| awk -F\, '{ print $1}')
tempout2=$(vnstat -h| tail -n 2| awk -F\  '{ print $11}'| tail -n 1| awk -F\, '{ print $2}')
o=$tempout1$tempout2
bandwidth_out_unit=$(vnstat -h| tail -n 9| awk -F\) '{ print $6}'| head -n 1|awk -F\( '{ print $2}')
#echo $bandwidth_out_unit
case "$bandwidth_out_unit" in
KiB)    bandwidth_out_number_Byte=$(echo "$o*1024"| bc)
;;
MiB)    bandwidth_out_number_Byte=$(echo "$o*1024*1024"|bc)
;;
GiB)    bandwidth_out_number_Byte=$(echo "$o*1024*1024*1024"|bc)
;;
TiB)    bandwidth_out_number_Byte=$(echo "$o*1024*1024*1024*1024"|bc)
;;
esac
#echo $bandwidth_out_number_Byte

echo $bandwidth_out_number_Byte


my expectation is to output the total_outbound_for_current_hour but instead it is output nothing can you fix that btw I don't get it. How I know I run ./fileexample.sh command
kindly check the output from command vnstat
root@vmi1774425:~# vnstat -h

     hour        rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
 2024-04-30
     11:00      4.66 MiB |    8.23 MiB |   12.89 MiB |   30.02 kbit/s
     12:00      6.52 MiB |   10.13 MiB |   16.65 MiB |   38.80 kbit/s
     13:00      7.71 MiB |   16.90 MiB |   24.61 MiB |   57.35 kbit/s
     14:00      6.81 MiB |   10.03 MiB |   16.83 MiB |   39.23 kbit/s
     15:00      7.08 MiB |   10.80 MiB |   17.88 MiB |   41.65 kbit/s
     16:00      6.61 MiB |   10.30 MiB |   16.91 MiB |   42.99 kbit/s
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------

also the output of  vnstat --oneline b
1;eth0;2024-04-30;46370486;77009098;123379584;5429;2024-04;46370486;77009098;123379584;5429;46370486;77009098;123379584


What is the unfiltered output of vnstat looking like?  (I think the output is based on the settings in your config...)

@Luuk I added the command vnstat -h the values is taking from there I think there is issue with that I never write shell script but that what I get.

vnstat -h | tail -n 2| awk -F\  '{ print $11}'| tail -n 1 does not produce output, which you could have checked when your debugged your own script.

@Luuk this is not my own script this is the thing I am not shell script writer and I have issue with this script and cause me not to integrate it with monitor zabbix

@Luuk there is a small change must be done two make that script work where I don't know

Option 1) Learn shell scripting  2) Find a programmer who can (and will) understand your script. Stackoverflow is not a free code solving problems website for non-programmers.  3) (tip for the programmer you might find):; rewrite the script using vnstat --oneline b

From the stackoverflow/tour page: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

oops, the output of vnstat --oneline b does not shot hourly info, so that would be of no-use, seeing that -h is being used.

What is the expected output (based on the output of vnstat -h in your question)? (Because that script is ..... , broken!)

Stack Overflow is a site for developers. We're here to help you if you're stuck trying to fix your own code, we're not here to fix someone else's code on your behalf.

I don't know @Luuk try to help me please

Assuming the vnStat version you are using isn't some legacy release, you could simplify all that to just vnstat --json h 1 | jq .interfaces[0].traffic.hour[0].tx

@TeemuToivola I kind of does not get you but yes the old different release show different position of data can you create an answer and rewrite the code

Which version of vnStat do you have? vnstat --version

@TeemuToivola vnStat 2.10 by Teemu Toivola 

If you really get no output at all, I conclude that bandwidth_out_unit is not one of the values you list in your case statement.  I would add a printf %s "$bandwidth_out_unit" | xxd to see that exactly is stored on this variable.

The shell script in question is trying to extract the outbound traffic (tx) for the current hour from the vnStat hourly output that has been intended for human use and then convert the value to bytes. The reason why the script no longer works is because it has been designed to use the text graphical output style that vnStat used for the hourly output when the -h parameter was given during versions 1.x. In version 2.0, the -h output was renamed -hg (hours graph) and -h now produces a list mode output resulting in the script blindly trying to extract fields that no longer exist.
While the script could be modified to work again by replacing -h with -hg, that wouldn't be the correct solution as the output will still be affected by at least the used system locale and vnStat's output style settings.
The correct solution is to use an output intended to be machine readable. For this vnStat provides --json. Assuming the jq command is available, the full script can be simplified to one line:
vnstat --json h 1 | jq '.interfaces[0].traffic.hour[0].tx'

--json instructs vnStat to output json
h results in only hourly data being shown in the output
1 results in only the last hour being shown
jq is used to extract the correct field from the output
.interfaces[0].traffic.hour[0].tx instructs jq to read the first interface, select the traffic section, select the first hour and then show  tx value (which is always in bytes when vnstat --json is used)

If the used system has more than one interface (or even if there's only one), it's recommended to pass also the -i parameter to specify the wanted interface. For example, for eth0, the command would be vnstat --json h 1 -i eth0 | jq '.interfaces[0].traffic.hour[0].tx'
If jq isn't available and cannot be installed, the --xml output may be easier to parse with shell commands: vnstat --xml h 1 -i eth0 | grep '<hour id' | cut -d\> -f21 | cut -d\< -f1

The more reliable way to extract content from XML output would be with xmllint --xpath. The approach suggested in the comment is extremely fragile -- it would break, for example, if any other attribute is added before id, even though the order of attributes doesn't change meaning; or if the XML is in a future version of vnstat pretty-printed and split onto distinct lines; or if new fields are added that means that it's no longer the 21st > that precedes the desired value, etc etc.

If you have neither jq nor an xmllint version that provides --xpath, I would suggest using Python (which has both JSON parsing and XML parsing in its standard library). We have examples of embedding Python in a shell script for this purpose already present elsewhere in our knowledge base, shown f/e in some answers to Parsing JSON with UNIX tools.

(In a past life I maintained an API that had clients using syntax-unaware string parsing to consume my output, and getting bug reports from them after making implementation changes that impacted output in ways that any compliant parser would have ignored was extremely frustrating; I would think this would be a situation you would want to avoid setting yourself up for here).

BTW, it's somewhat safer to quote your jq expression -- if it's not in quotes then the shell can see the [0]s as glob expressions, triggering either incorrect behavior or outright errors if the nullglob or or failglob shell options are enabled.
